# Exp:resso Store - Prevent updating mapped member fields from checkout

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to prevent Store from updating mapped fields during checkout unless an option to update is selected? Specifically billing and shipping addresses?

I'm using exp:user to allow a user to save a default billing and shipping address in their account. These are mapped to Store's order fields and everything works hunky-dory, except default behavior for Store is to update these details if they're changed during checkout (as detailed as a "remember my details" feature here: https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/settings_order_fields.html).

I would only like to update the mapped fields if an option in the checkout is checked. Something along the lines of an "update my default billing/shipping address" option.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Store that would allow you to selectively choose when to update the mapped member fields based upon a conditional or checkbox functionality. You could create a little extension to enable that kind of functionality (available [extension hooks](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html)).

Alternatively and I have not tested something like this with Store you could use [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) which allows users to create multiple address profiles. Then in your templates you would have to manually create the store checkout fields so that you had

```
<input type="text" name="billing_address1" value="{profile_edit_field_for_billing_address1}" />
```

If you were going to use this approach you would probably not want to have the member fields mapped.